# Hair dynamics doesn't work after subdivide

Tags: particles, physics, hair

I was created clothes, and wanted to create hair.

Now, hair dynamics work fine before I subdivided. I used <kbd>F3</kbd> to search for select the roots and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad Plus</kbd> to select other vertices, right clicked and selected *Subdivide*. Repeated it, and then I deselected it.

I styled the hair and then the hair dynamics doesn't work.

I'm on Blender 3.2 with AMD Radeon Vega 6 Mobile Graphics. My computer's not built for rendering, so I guess that's the problem.

I searched around the devforums of blender and it's a common issue, also, the hair likes to poke around the face mesh even though the group is right above the forehead. The loose strands doesn't appear in particle edit.

[Video](https://youtu.be/bQlC49rWKW8)

Comment: I don't think your computer is the reason for this. Maybe it's a cache problem? (Hair settings > Cache). Try to bake it on disk?

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.